# DateTimePicker is not showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am facing an issue with the datetime picker in jquery in MVC4. Here is my code:

```
 @Html.TextBox("RELIEVING_DATE", Model.RELIEVING_DATE)


$(function () {
    $("#RELIEVING_DATE").datepicker();
}
```

But the datetime picker is not showing and showing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inline' of undefined"

In my model `RELIEVING_DATE` is a nullable field. I want to give a default value to it.

Please help.

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inline' of undefined

Comment: Did you load jquery before your code runs? How about you try: `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#RELIEVING_DATE").datepicker(); });`

Comment: Is datepicker works, when you use code example from jquery-ui page (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: @vonv. Aside from a missing closing parenthesis and semi-colon, the jQuery shown is the same as your suggestion - it's an alternate form of the jQuery ready event.

Comment: actually semicolumn in my code.but i mised in this queston.i have one more model field DOB,that not nullable .its firing daytetime picker.

Comment: @vonv. Your method worked for me.  I was calling datepicker() in a partial view so I needed to do it on document.ready.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice in the script you posted is that your `$(function () {` is missing a closing `);` at the end.

Also make sure you have properly included the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts in your page. If you are using bundles you might need to have the following scripts before the script that is attaching the date picker:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Normally the `~/bundles/jquery` bundle is already included in the `_Layout.cshtml` if you used the Internet Application Template to create your project.

Another thing you should verify is that you do not have multiple fields with the same id. Also if this `@Html.TextBox` is inside an editor template the id might not be `#RELIEVING_DATE` but prefixed with the navigational property, for example `#SomeProperty_RELIEVING_DATE`. Look at the generated HTML in the browser to see the exact id. You could also assign a class to the field:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RELIEVING_DATE, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

and then:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: thanks its working.one more question how to set the default date as current date.

Comment: In the controller action that is rendering this view you could set the property on the model: `model.RELIEVING_DATE = DateTime.Now;`.

Comment: thanks.Is it possible to set the date format(dd/mm/yyyy) in date time picker?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inline' of undefined" error still showing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this same error, and it was because I was loading the scripts multiple times.

I had the below on the main page, and the sub-pages within.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```